# Convert Polar Equation to Rectangular Equation

Tags: trigonometry, polar-coordinates

I have been trying to convert the polar equation to rectangular.

$U(1,\theta) = 10+3*sin(\theta)-10*cos(2*\theta)$

I started off my multiplying everything by r and using the trig identity for cos($2*\theta$).

$= 10 * r +3* r *sin(\theta)-10*r*(2*cos^2(\theta)-1)$

Then I distributed everything out.

$= 10 * r +3* r *sin(\theta)-20*r*cos^2(\theta) + 10*r$

Combined like terms.

$= 20* r + 3* r *sin(\theta) - 20*r*cos^2(\theta)$

At this point if I use

$x^2+y^2 =r^2$

x = rcosθ

y = rsinθ

y/x =tanθ

I get a bit confused because I end up with the $r*cos^2(\theta)$ term where I am unable to do anything.

Any explanation will help.

Thanks, Mary

Comment: I guess $U(1,\theta)$ is the special case of $U(r,\theta)$ for $r=1$. But there are a lot of ambiguities in the RHS. If it is independent of  $r$ then you substitute from the definitions $\cos \theta = x/r$ and $\sin \theta = y/r$. If actually $10=10\times r$ or $10=9+r$ etc,  you will run into trouble with these ambiguities. The only way to proceed is to get the complete $U(r,\theta).$

Comment: If this equation were U(r,θ)=10+3∗sin(θ)−10∗cos(2∗θ), am I solving it correctly?

Comment: I think I got it. I treated r and θ as independent variables. I multiplied by r^2 and simplified everything down to 20*y^2+3*y*sqr(x^2+y^2). Then using the initial condition I let r=1=sqr(x^2+y^2). So, my equation reduces to 20y^2+3y.

Comment: @MariaJimenez   - You should write that comment as an answer. You are allowed to answer your own questions.